# Can you launch a process on top of the topmost window? (csharp wpf)

Tags: c#, c, wpf, topmost

Can you launch a process on top of the topmost window? (csharp wpf)
 I have the following, but the current window before this one ( a wpf window using window class that has topmost=true ), remains on top of the process when the process is launched..

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(MY_CALC_PATH))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process helpProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    helpProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
    helpProcess.Start();
    helpProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
    BringWindowToTop(helpProcess.MainWindowHandle);
    SetWindowPos(helpProcess.MainWindowHandle, myCurrentTopmostWinHnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE_);
}
```

Comment: [What if two programs did this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)?

Comment: In wpf I beleive that all topmost windows are above all non-topmost and the 'active' topmost is above all other topmost, if that helps sLak. for my question though, i want to know how to get a process that is launched to be marked as topmost as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Calculator window as a child window of your TopMost window by calling [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, this approach [has drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459874/good-or-evil-setparent-win32-api-between-different-processes).

Comment: This is a good idea, but in my case it will not work because the child window opens up inside the constrained boundaries of the parent so it is too small.

Comment: Marking this answer as it was the most useful. I instead used a workaround (made the other windows at the same level instead of any of them being topmost, and then set the window which needed to be viewed as active).