# c# open explorer window ont top

Tags: c#, window, layer, explorer

I'm using

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", Application.StartupPath);

To open the applications path with a button press, but the window opens behind my application, how can I get it on top?

Comment: your answer is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312535/can-you-launch-a-process-on-top-of-the-topmost-window-csharp-wpf)

keep the hardwork :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to **TopMost** property of the form may be true, or any of the properties of the form is making your application to stay on top. Just try to change the form properties and you will get the required result