# Attach window to external process

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user32

I'm writing an application in C# which needs to attach one of its own windows to a window owned by another process. I tried using the SetParent function from the windows api, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to do this?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetParent(int hWndChild, int hWndNewParent);

    private void AttachWindow(int newParent) {
    SetParent(this.Handle, newParent);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your P/Invoke declaration is wrong. Handles are represented by `IntPtr`, not `Int32`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Now maybe you should avoid "attaching" a window to another process. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459874/good-or-evil-setparent-win32-api-between-different-processes).