# Prevent the hosting application from losing focus by hosted one

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, focus

I am using the usual `SetParent` WinAPI to host in my application A another third party application B, using .Net framework.

However, it is confusing the users, because when a user doing something in the hosted app B, windows will make my app A inactive and grays out the title bar, as it should be actually.

My question: is there any workaround or way to avoid that? I mean to keep my app A active even when one works in the hosted application B?

Comment: Unless application B is prepared to be re-parented, this isn't going to work reliably. Ask the vendor of application B if their application is prepared to be re-parented.

Comment: @IInspectable I see, this is not possible currently.... thank you anyway.

Comment: I had a very hard time working with parent and child windows belonging to different processes. I would strongly advise against it. Also, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459874/good-or-evil-setparent-win32-api-between-different-processes