# Is there some way to open multiple apps or programs with one GUI?

Tags: windows, user-interface, running-other-programs

So my question is: Is it possible to open, for instance, Discord, Chrome, Spotify or any files in "one process/window"? What I mean by that is, if I wanted to be able to open 3 apps but I don't want it to take so many tabs and so much space, I would want to have those 3 apps in one window. So lets say I were working on 3 different projects and I don't want to always switch desktops or look for the apps everytime I switch projects, I would just want to alt+tab to that project. It would also be nice to be able to prioritise one app in task manager instead of 5. If that is not possible then my thought was to create a "screen sharing program" that captures the other apps and displays it into a UI that I could design. If it were possible, how would I go about starting that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, no. You could however try creating different desktops on Windows.

See this page for more information:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-desktops-in-windows-36f52e38-5b4a-557b-2ff9-e1a60c976434

Comment: If that is not possible then, my thought was to create a "screen sharing program" that captures the other apps and displays it into a UI that I could design.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to put a process's window inside another process's window. I did it in a very limited case once, but that involved placing a non-interactive (display-only) window inside of an application I wrote which was used by only a few people. I have no idea how well it would work with multiple interactive windows.

Use [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) in your "screen sharing program" to place the desired applications inside your window. However, take note of [Adrian McCarthy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460542/4896941) to [Good or evil - SetParent() win32 API between different processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459874/good-or-evil-setparent-win32-api-between-different-processes), and note Raymond Chen's blog posts from the comments:

- [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)
- [Sharing an input queue takes what used to be asynchronous and makes it synchronous, like focus changes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143).